# Python difference between a list and multi-dimensional list

Tags: python

I need some help, the following is what I want:

```
list1 = [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"], ["d", "4"]]
list2 = ["b", "c"]
list3 = []

list1 - list2 = list3
print(list3)

Expected Output:
[["a", "1"], ["d", "4"]]
```

I know that you can do the following with one-dimensional lists:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = ["b", "c"]

list3 = list(set(list1) - set(list2))
print(list3)

Output: ["a", "d"]
```

So, how do I do the above but with multi-dimensional lists and output of a multi-dimensional list as well?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use lists? Because this is a perfect use case for a dictionary with key:value pairs

Comment: `list1` can be seen as an association list. If the keys (the first elements of the sublists) are unique, you can create a mapping with `d = dict(list1)`. Then you can remove the desired keys with, for example, `for k in list2: d.pop(k)`.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with list comprehension. Essentially what we are doing is, retaining the sublists from `list1` that their first value (the character) does not exists in the values of list2:

```
list1 = [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"], ["d", "4"]]
list2 = ["b", "c"]

list3 = [item for item in list1 if item[0] not in list2]
print(list3)
```

Output:

```
[['a', '1'], ['d', '4']]
```

However this is to solve this particular example with the particular data you provide. As explained in comments, working with dictionaries is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

G. Anderson is right, it seems that you're in a good use case for dictionnaries.

If you'll stuck with this data structure (that *could* be the case if your inner lists can have more than 2 elements), you'll have to use **list comprehension**, this syntax is not supported out-of-the-box.

my suggestion

```py
list1 = [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"], ["d", "4"]]
ignored_keys = ['b', 'c']
list3 = [val for val in list1 if val[0] not in ignored_keys]
print(list3)
Output: [['a', '1'], ['d', '4']]
```

Comment: you're right, thanks :) I forgot a bit in the comprehension part

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer using filter and a lambda function.

```
list1 = [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"], ["d", "4"]]
list2 = ["b", "c"]
list3 = []

list3 = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] not in list2, list1))
print(list3)

# [["a", "1"], ["d", "4"]]
```